# UNION ALL from each row of a results set

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have a view that runs quickly if I feed it a single parameter, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM v_myView WHERE myVal = 'thisValue';
```

If I ask it for multiple values `IN`, it evaluates the entire view's data, and picks the results from the data, in an operation taking around 20 seconds. So this is slow:

```
SELECT * FROM v_myView WHERE myVal IN (SELECT theseValues FROM myTable);
```

I have it in mind that for a dataset I know is small, it would be quicker to take all the results from `SELECT theseValues FROM myTable` query their matches individually from `v_myView` and `UNION ALL` the results such that I'm effectively generating the query:

```
SELECT * FROM v_myView WHERE myVal = 'thisValue1'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM v_myView WHERE myVal = 'thisValue2'
UNION ALL
etc...;
```

Is there any way to force this to happen in a "simple" query without using a stored procedure or dynamic sql, or am I just going to have to do this long-hand?

Comment: To improve the code in your view you need to provide the query inside the view, and get stats on the query/table for indexes/etc.

Comment: Is `myVal` an indexed column? Get the execution plan to see where the bottleneck is happening.

Comment: @Brad I think it's more of an order of execution issue. The view's logic is essentially bypassed if I supply it with this particular parameter. But only if it's supplied as a single parameter. If I use `IN`, it has to fully evaluate the view and then pick out the rows it wants from the results. What I want is a way to bypass the logic up-front.

Comment: A `UNION ALL` is going to make this worse, not quicker. I suspect the problem is a lack of covering indexes on the objects referenced by `v_myView` (and there not being one on the column `myVal `) and that `theseValues` in `MyTable` is also not indexed. Meaning that the RDBMS has to make scans of the tables to perform the matching; which for a large amount of rows *is* going to be slow.

Comment: Please post your plans for both queries.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a look at the execution plan and the structure of the underlying table and the view would have allowed to answer the question better.

Usually use of EXISTS gives the best performance out of the 3 normal frequently used ways to achieve this:

1. EXISTS
2. INNER JOIN
3. IN

However the comparison depends on the structure and indexing of the underlying tables.

- EXISTS in a way short circuits the search whenever it finds a match which can make it better than the other 2 approaches.

**Query:**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    v_myView V 
WHERE   EXISTS   (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM   myTable T
                    WHERE  T.theseValues = V.myVal
                 );
```

But the query should also be covered with required indexes to be able to get good performance:

1. myVal column of the underlying table of v_myView view should have a nonclustered rowstore index (unless myVal is already the clustered index key of that table).
2. theseValues column of myTable should have a nonclustered rowstore index (unless theseValues is already the clustered index key of the table)
3. Do you need to fetch all the columns of the view v_myView in your final result? I would suggest you to fetch only the required columns in result. The selected columns should be covered by use of either nonclustered rowstore index with INCLUDE clause, or create a single nonclustered columnstore index covering those columns per underlying table.